# How do I kill a deployment in AWS Opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

How do I kill a long running deployment in Amazon Opsworks?

We run deployments to an integration environment everytime we commit to our code repo. Our current deployments are taking a long time, which causes deployments to stack on top of each other in Opsworks. We're working on making our deployment process for the application more efficient, but until we get that sorted out, is there an easy way to kill a deployment so we can just run the latest one in the queue?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no easy way.

There is no API call to cancel them.
So the only possible approach would be checking on the instance if it's necessary to run the deployment or skip it. You can achieve this with a custom cookbook.